# Choice of sites while flagging posts as beloning to other SE-site

Tags: feature-request

When flagging a post as off-topic I can choose that "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange Network". From there I can choose one of 5 sites (meta, superuser, tex, dba, sharepoint).

It is not clear to me why you can choose superuser, since one level up you can already flag this question to be better asked at the superuser-site.

But what I am missing most is the ability to choose another site like e.g. math.superuser.com (or other Stack Exchange sites). Are there any plans to broaden the list or is the omission intentional?

Comment: I think those are the 5 which stack overflow people are likely to know if it's on topic on. Anything else is considered best to go through a moderator

Comment: It's *very* intentional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to flag a post to be migrated to a site that isn't included in the "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange Network" list, the preferred method is to flag the question for moderator attention and enter your justification into the detail box that appears upon clicking this flag reason.

There is no need to include a full list of Stack Exchange sites in this list as this list is intended to only include the handful of Stack Exchange sites related to the site you're currently on.

This goes in general as well, if you feel there is a reason to flag a post and there isn't a reason in the list of available reasons that match why you're flagging it, just flag it for moderator attention so that a moderator can consider your reason for flagging the post.

Comment: Perhaps it should be noted in that dialog that this is the preferred method? I had no idea until I came here and found this question. I think that a simple search for a StackExchange network site would suffice, but I'm not opposed to the flag for moderation attention method - there just needs to be some clear instruction that this is the proper course of action.